# PHP Google Calendar API v3 - Updating a Event

Tags: php, events, google-calendar-api

I'm getting an error when trying to update an event in google calendar using the v3 api.
I try this code:

```
          $event = new Google_Event();
      $event->setSymmary('TEST');
      $updated = $cal->events->update("calendarID", "eventID", $event);
```

But I don't know why it sends me the error : Missing end time.
It's necessary to insert the end time to update a existing event?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Event must have a start time and an end time. You are creating a new event object which has neither of the two and you are trying to replace an existing event with that. I propose you first read the existing event, update the field and then do the update call. Also it should be setSummary, not setSymmary.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are creating a new Event. To update an existing event, you have to:

1) Get the event:

```
$event = $service->events->get($calendarId, $eventId);
```

2) Change this event:

```
$event->setSummary('TEST');
```

3) Send this new event to replace the old:

```
$service->events->update($calendarId, $event->getId(), $event);
```